# How can I predeploy container images on a device managable with Eclipse Kanto?

Tags: yocto, eclipse-iot

We are building a system image for a device with Yocto, and we also can build container images, that can be stored somewhere on the filesystem of the device.

The idea now is, to have the containers be started automatically, when the device is powered on, even if the device never had any network connection.
When the device is connected later, those containers should be managed with Kanto.
Is this possible, how could we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kanto Container Management component unfortunately does not have this feature out-of-the-box. A possible solution could be e.g. to add a boot-time executed shell script to spin the desired containers if you have added the images in the device's container image cache build-time.

More info regarding the state of the described feature you can catch up in [the dedicated Kanto GitHub ticket](https://github.com/eclipse-kanto/container-management/issues/95).